# Show progress bar in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I want to show a circle progress bar while table is generate in background. My code in async task:

```
class DoWork extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    Context context;

    public DoWork(Context con){
        this.context = con;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        setContentView(R.layout.content_progress);
        pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                setContentView(new TableMainLayout(context));
            }
        });

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

Code in content_progress.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.standart.trainschedule.ProgressActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_progress">

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

new TableMainLayout(context) - generate a table layout with data and also it is an UI, that why I use runOnUiThread() in doInBackground()

The problem is when I run my app on phone it doesn't show a progress bar. It just frozen my app for 5 sec. and than show me a generated table.

What should I do to show progress bar ?

Comment: **Never** do `runOnUiThread` within an AsyncTask. It defeats the whole purpose of an AsyncTask

Comment: Is your layout fetching data from the internet or something like that?

Comment: nasch, TableMainLayout take data from data base.

Answer (score 0):

Your ProgressBar is in the layout content_progress. But you are replacing that layout with your TableLayout and with that the previous view is being overwritten.

What you can try is to predefine the TableLayout and ProgressBar in an XML and set it as a the content view, or define a RelativeLayout programmatically and add both TableLayout and ProgressBar as views

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302232/centering-progressbar-programmatically-in-android) where it has been given how to add a progressBar programmatically. You can implement a similar method for the TableLayout also.

Comment: I can't predefine the TableLayout in an XML because it generates dynamically using data from SQLite

Comment: Rishabh Tatiraju, I can create progress bar in XML but how to include this XML without additional setContentView() ?

Comment: @gigs follow that link...it shows how to set views as a child of a parent layout and set the view.

Answer (score 0):

The main purpose on `AsyncTask` is load something in background thread and then deliver it to UI thread. `doInBackground` runs in non UI thread, but you make it run in UI one...

So if your widget generate from SQL data, just generate it on `doInBackground` and execute `setContentView` in `onPostExecute`.

Comment: According to your logic where should I save data retrieved from data base in doInBackground ? If my data base has more than 800 rows.

Comment: You have to change `AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>` to `AsyncTask<Void, Void, TableMainLayout>`. Then change appropriate methods. And your `doInBackgound` method should be like this: `return new TableMainLayout(context)`. And then in `postExecute` you can call `setContentView(tableMainLayout)`.
And read documentation: http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html .