# ProgressDialog showing white background dialog with progress inside it

Tags: android, android-dialog

I am trying to show a simple progress (indeterminate) to indicate that it is loading.

Here is the code  I am using

```
ProgressDialog progressDiag = new ProgressDialog(this);
progressDiag.setIndeterminate(true);
progressDiag.show();
```

Where this refers to the current AppCompatActivity

However this is what I am getting

[image]

As you can see, it is displaying White dialog with progress bar at the side of it!
Why is the progress circle inside a white dialog, how can I get rid of that or at least make it as big as the progress circle (and in the middle)?

This looks like there is contents missing

Thank you

Comment: This is a standard progress dialog, if you supply a text message it's going to be displayed to the right of progress indicator. Let the user know exactly what's happening. ***///*** If you don't want the dialog, don't use `ProgressDialog`, that's self-explanatory. Put a `ProgressBar` in your main layout instead.

Comment: use custom dialog layout. That is a standard progress dialog with the space for text (which you don't set)

Comment: Is there a way I can add progress bar dynamically to overlay the middle of the screen and block the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ProgressBar for this

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pb"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html

Comment: Is there a way I can add progress bar dynamically to overlay the middle of the screen and block the user?

Comment: You can look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302232/centering-progressbar-programmatically-in-android

Comment: Thank you but that won't block the user. It is essentially part of the layout