# Show ProgressBar programattically while user logging on

Tags: xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I found this class at [Centering ProgressBar Programmatically in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302232/centering-progressbar-programmatically-in-android) which would display a progressbar programmatically, problem is it's an Xamarin Android Studio example and I'm trying to convert it to Xamarin for Visual Studio 2017.  This is the code that I have successfully converted with those lines that I can't seem to find a Xamarin VS 2017 equivalent for.

```
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace OML_Android
{
    class ProgressBarHandler
    {
        private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
        private Context mContext;

        public ProgressBarHandler(Context context)
        {
            mContext = context;

            ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup)((Activity)context).FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.Content).RootView;

            mProgressBar = new ProgressBar(context, null, Android.Resource.Attribute.ProgressBarStyleLarge);

            // there is no setIndeterminate method for progressbar
            mProgressBar.setIndeterminate(true);

            // I cannot find an equivilent for LayoutParams
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent);

            RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(context);

            // No equivalent for Gravity.CENTER
            rl.SetGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            rl.AddView(mProgressBar);

            layout.AddView(rl, params);

            hide();
        }

        public void show()
        {
            mProgressBar.Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Visible;
        }

        public void hide()
        {
            mProgressBar.Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Invisible;
        }
    }
}
```

Once I have this converted and working I want it to overlay my logon view until the view finishes processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I help you transform Java code to C#, there is running GIF.

[image]

There is code.

```
    class ProgressBarHandler
{
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private Context mContext;

    public ProgressBarHandler(Context context)
    {
        mContext = context;

        ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup)((Activity)context).FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.Content).RootView;

        mProgressBar = new ProgressBar(context, null, Android.Resource.Attribute.ProgressBarStyleLarge);

        // there is no setIndeterminate method for progressbar
      //  mProgressBar.SetIndeterminate(true);
        mProgressBar.Indeterminate = true;
        // I cannot find an equivilent for LayoutParams
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent);

        RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(context);

        // No equivalent for Gravity.CENTER
        rl.SetGravity(GravityFlags.Center   );
        rl.AddView(mProgressBar);

        layout.AddView(rl, layoutparams);

        hide();
    }

    public void show()
    {
        mProgressBar.Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Visible;
    }

    public void hide()
    {
        mProgressBar.Visibility = Android.Views.ViewStates.Invisible;
    }
}
```

You can use it directly like following code in Activity.

```
var progress= new ProgressBarHandler(this);
progress.show();
```

Comment: If above code is helpful, please do not forget to mark it answer, it will help others who have simialr issue, happy coding.

Comment: Sorry, but this is full of errors, for example;  What is `mContext`, it is not typed, c# requires it to be typed.  And `context` doesn't exist nor is it a type.  `Context` is (capital C).  I copied and pasted your code exactly as you have it here and it generates 16 separate errors.

Comment: Much better ... now I can compile and test .... copy and paste the progressBarHandler code you have on github and I'll mark it as the answer.  Thank you.